# Change tox workdir

Tags: python, virtualenv, tox

Looking on the `tox global settings` section from tox documentation, the `.tox` directory which is working dir, is created in directory where `tox.ini` is located:

```
toxworkdir={toxinidir}/.tox(PATH)
    Directory for tox to generate its environments into, will be created if 
    it does not exist.
```

**Is there a way to change this location?**

For instance, I have a project as follows:

```
awesome_project/
├── main.py
├── src
│   └── app.py
└── tox.ini
```

I want to execute `tox.ini` from `awesome_project` dir, but want to write `.tox` dir in `/tmp/.tox` not in `awesome_project/.tox`.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{toxinidir}/.tox` is just a default value that you can change in `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
toxworkdir=/tmp/.tox
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working.
There is also possible set this location per specific environment using envdir variavle.

Comment: If you have two unrelated projects which use the same toxworkdir, this will cause you trouble. And all files in /tmp get removed after a reboot (at least on linux). I would suggest /var/tmp/MY_PROJECT/.tox

Answer (score 1):

You can change the working directory from the command line:

```
tox --workdir /tmp/.tox
```

It may be useful if you want to use the same `tox.ini` file in two different computers with different working directories.