# How to use 'cd' within tox?

Tags: bash, tox

Within a `tox.ini` (tox 3.25.1) I am trying to run `cd` to create a link

```
[testenv:docs]
commands =
    make clean
    make html SPHINXOPTS="-v"
    cd build/html
    ln -s ../../source/www/projects .
allowlist_externals = 
    make 
    /bin/bash
```

But neither

```
allowlist_externals = 
    /bin/bash
```

nor

```
allowlist_externals = 
    bash
```

nor

```
allowlist_externals = 
    cd
```

seem to work. I always get the error

```
ERROR: InvocationError for command could not find executable cd
```

So what is the trick? And where is it documented?

As [this documentation](https://tox.wiki/en/3.25.1/example/basic.html?highlight=bash#allowing-non-virtualenv-commands) seems to be outdated or incorrect.

The linked answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503796/change-tox-workdir) seems to be completely unrelated. I do not want to change the directory in which tox is executed. Please read.

Comment: `cd` is not an external command. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish? Running `cd` in a subprocess is pointless anyway, as it cannot change the current directory of its parent process (in this case, `tox`).

Comment: As you can see in the question I want to create a link

Comment: Simply `ln -s ../../source/www/projects build/html/` should work. The first argument to `ln -s` can be anything, the symlink will only be resolved when you attempt to open it (and so any relative path should be relative to the link's location, not the directory where you run the command, perhaps confusingly).

Comment: For these type of things, I would put the commands (`make`, `cd`, `ln`) into a shell script and run the script from tox.

Comment: Never mind, you suggestion for `ln` seems to work now. I wonder why the full path ln (ln -s /home/me/folder/here/and/there ...) does not work.

Comment: Perhaps that path is not part of the virtual envrionment created by tox?

Comment: But still - the documentation does not seem to be correct. Do you agree?